# How do I instantiate java.security.Principal? All the subclasses are deprecated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java.security

I have a Spring API service which accepts Principal.

```
public ResponseEntity<ApiCustomResponse> create(Principal principal, UrlInfoData urlinfo) throws ApiException;
```

The Principal is created automatically by Spring for OAuth2 API calls. I would like to use the same service for the web page admin interface.

```
@Autowired
private IShortUrlService apiService;
...
    Principal principal = new Principal();
    apiService.create(principal, urlinfo);
```

I want to instantiate the Principal with the current logged in admin user's name. However, all the instantiating classes are deprecated. How can I instantiate a Principal to pass to the service?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `java.security.Principal` is an interface, why don't you implement it?

```
Principal principal = new Principal() {

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return adminName;
        }

    }
apiService.create(principal, urlinfo);
```

Also, you can get the Principal for the current logged in user with: `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`

Comment: The shorter way of doing this is with a lambda:
`final Principal principal = () -> adminName;`